# Do Planck mass black holes rotate, and can they absorb more energy?

Tags: black-holes

I understand black holes rotate, or at least the ones we observe do.

If Planck mass black holes exist, and do not decay further, then:
(1) Would such a black hole still rotate?
(2) Would such a black hole be able to absorb energy, and what kinds of energy?
(3) I've been told large size black holes have about 20% of their energy in their rotation, would it be the same for a Planck mass black hole?

Comment: What theory are you asking about? Classical GR? The semiclassical combo of GR and QM that predicts Harking radiation? Some string theory? Some other speculative theory of quantum gravity?

Comment: I don't know which theories are applicable.If it's a matter of choosing which theory supports a Planck mass black hole continually rotating through absorbing energy, then I'd like to know if there is such a theory (if more than one, which is considered the most sound), and how sound is it considered by quantum physicists.

Comment: No current theory of Planck-scale black holes is considered sound. This is the kind of system that requires a theory of quantum gravity, and all such theories are currently speculative. Which is “most sound” is a matter of opinion.

Comment: There are standard ways to calculate how classical black holes absorb and scatter energy, such as an electromagnetic wave. But as far as I know, all physicists assume these calculations are not accurate at Planck scale.